# How -exactly- do I remove a specific directory, from my PATH, in OSX, Mavericks?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, path

Ok - so this issue has become somewhat of a white whale for me. I have browsed some of the questions here, but I cannot seem to figure out how to, very simply, delete a directory from my PATH. (I should also add that I am very to to Mac, making the transition from Windows).

So: I have gathered that I can make a .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc etc, to ADD files to my PATH. I think I get that.

However what I cannot seem to find a direct answer to, is: How do I simply delete a specific existing directory, from my PATH? This is all I would honestly like to do.

Thank you.

**EDIT: Why I want to remove a directory from PATH:**

Long story short, homebrew put a directory into my PATH, that it no longer needs. It says I can remove it from PATH, and so this is why I would like to remove it. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: In your .bashrc (and others), you're not limited to appending to your PATH, you can also simply define a complete PATH (ignoring whatever it used to have)... but why you would want to remove a standard entry is curious; can you say more about what you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mah No worries, I edited the question for the reason why. Also FWIW, I dont have a .bashrc, but if I can make one to overwrite the PATH, then I guess that would work...

Answer (score 4):

It depends where the PATH is being set. If you use bash, the path could be set in any of the following:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

<sup>This list is in the order that the files are read (by bash). Later files override earlier files.</sup>

Check the above in reverse order for `export PATH` which will write your PATH variable.

You should be able to find where it's set by launching your shell with `-x`.

Also check `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d` for paths that are set before your shell is started.

If all else fails, you can set the PATH yourself to override its current contents. Run `echo $PATH`, then paste your PATH after `export PATH` in your ~/.bashrc and make your desired modifications. As ~/.bashrc is the last one read, it will override any earlier modifications to your PATH.

If you use zsh, it's probably in ~/.zshrc or a sourced file.

Comment: Also note that most homebrew recipies are very well behaved and do not modify your configuration files. They suggest commands you can run to do the modifications at the end of the install. And do note: if you're not running `bash` the ways `PATH` get set will differ from above.

Comment: Hmm...so the last four files do not exist for me, and I checked the first two, but that python directory is not there...

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond What do you get if you run `bash -x`? You should see your PATH being set to include that directory, which you can then grep the files to find where that is.

Comment: Umm...weird... I get: "++ git_info_for_prompt"...also, that messed the way the prompt looks like now... 0_0

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond Is that all? There should be many lines that get written. (You can get back by closing/opening Terminal or pressing ⌃D)

Comment: Ok, so here is everything it shows: http://pastie.org/9248073

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond Interesting; try `bash -xi`

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah, same exact output...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14858/discussion-between-george-garside-and-thegrapebeyond).

Comment: +1 for `/etc/paths.d/` - I spent hours for this